# How to use `getLastAttempted()` in laravel 5.3？

Tags: php, laravel

How to use `getLastAttempted()` in laravel 5.3？

```
$user = auth()->getLastAttempted();
    dd($user);

    if (!$user->activated) {
        return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'This account has not been activated.');
    }
```

I want to check a user is `activated` or not when login (There is a `activated` field in `users` table ),
I add the code above to `login()` method below of `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`,

as follow:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);


        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

// start 
    $user = auth()->getLastAttempted();
        dd($user);

        if (!$user->activated) {
            return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'This account has not been activated.');
        }
   //end     

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }


        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

The result of  `dd($user);` is null.

What shoud I do?

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it make more sense to put your code chunks inside the if else statement?

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);


        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) { 

            // start 
            $user = \Auth::user();
            dd($user);

            if (!$user->activated) {
                //instead of redirecting, increment attempts and send failed response
                $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request); 
                return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
            }else{
                return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            }
            //end     


        }



        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the validateLogin function:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|exists:users,' . $this->username() . ',activated,1',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
```